# Smooth Scrolling to search bar input and exclude letters of the expression when compared the values of the case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm completely new to web development so have that in your mind. I´ve two questions. Nr1. How can i make a smooth scroll from the value that comes from the search bar to the section on my site that represents that value? I´ve tested

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#Nightmare").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

but that only works in my main function and direct when the page loaded I´m moved to the Nightmare section. I just want to use that in my sendToPage function for each section.

My second question is if that are any solutions if I want to make the case letters that matches the expressions more flexible? An example now if someone type nightmare it works but not if someone type Nightmare or night for example.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
       <title>A7X</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="a7x.css" type="text/css">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond|Ravi+Prakash" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
     <body>
     <h1 class="hide">Avenged Sevenfold lyrics</h1>
       <header><h1>We have one collective hope: The Earth</h1><img src="../bilder/avenged_sevenfold___logo__1__png__deathbat_by_lightsinaugust-d5klaeb.png" alt="Avenged Sevenfolds logo"></header>
       <nav>
       <p>Album Search</p>
         <form action="" onsubmit="return sendToPage()" method="post">
         <input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Album name">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
       </nav>
       <main>
         <div class="wrapper">
           <div class="ram" id="Stage">
             <details>
               <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>The Stage</li>
               <li>Paradigm</li>
               <li>Sunny Disposition</li>
               <li>God Damn</li>
               <li>Creating God</li>
               <li>Angels</li>
               <li>Simulation</li>
               <li>Higher</li>
               <li>Roman Sky</li>
               <li>Fermi Paradox</li>
               <li>Exist</li>
             </details>
            <img src="../bilder/The-Stage-Album-Cover-sept8_CMYK.jpg" alt="The Stage album">
           </div>
           <div class="ram" id="Hail">
             <details>
               <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>Shepherd of Fire</li>
               <li>Hail to the King</li>
               <li>Doing Time</li>
               <li>This Means War</li>
               <li>Requiem</li>
               <li>Crimson Day</li>
               <li>Heretic</li>
               <li>Coming Home</li>
               <li>Planets</li>
               <li>Acid Rain</li>
               <li>St. James</li>
             </details>
            <img src="../bilder/Hail-To-The-King.jpg" alt="Hail To The King Album">
           </div>
           <div class="ram" id="Nightmare">
           <details>
             <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>Nightmare</li>
               <li>Welcome to the Family</li>
               <li>Danger Line</li>
               <li>Buried Alive</li>
               <li>Natural Born Killer</li>
               <li>So Far Away</li>
               <li>God Hates Us</li>
               <li>Victim</li>
               <li>Tonight the World Dies</li>
               <li>Fiction</li>
               <li>Save Me</li>
               <li>Lost It All</li>
           </details>
            <img src="../bilder/Nightmare.jpg" alt="Nightmare Album">
           </div>
           <div class="ram" id="Self">
             <details>
               <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>Critical Acclaim</li>
               <li>Almost Easy</li>
               <li>Scream</li>
               <li>Afterlife</li>
               <li>Gunslinger</li>
               <li>Unbound (The Wild Ride)</li>
               <li>Brompton Cocktail</li>
               <li>Lost</li>
               <li>A Little Piece of Heaven</li>
               <li>Dear God</li>
               <li>Crossroads</li>
             </details>
            <img src="../bilder/Avenged-Sevenfold.jpg" alt="Avenged Sevenfold Album">
           </div>
           <div class="ram" id="City">
             <details>
               <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>Beast and the Harlot</li>
               <li>Burn It Down</li>
               <li>Blinded in Chains</li>
               <li>Bat Country</li>
               <li>Trashed and Scattered</li>
               <li>Seize the Day</li>
               <li>Sidewinder</li>
               <li>The Wicked End</li>
               <li>Strength of the World</li>
               <li>Betrayed</li>
               <li>M.I.A</li>
             </details>
            <img src="../bilder/City-Of-Evil.jpg" alt="City of Evil Album">
           </div>
           <div class="ram" id="Waking">
             <details>
               <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>Waking the Fallen</li>
               <li>Unholy Confessions</li>
               <li>Chapter Four</li>
               <li>Remenissions</li>
               <li>Desecrate Through Reverence</li>
               <li>Eternal Rest</li>
               <li>Second Heartbeat</li>
               <li>Radiant Eclipse</li>
               <li>I Won't See You Tonight (Part 1)</li>
               <li>I Won't See You Tonight (Part 2)</li>
               <li>Clairvoyant Disease</li>
               <li>And All Things Will End</li>
             </details>
            <img src="../bilder/Waking-The-Fallen.jpg" alt="Waking the Fallen Album">
           </div>
           <div class="ram" id="Sound">
             <details>
               <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
               <li>To End the Rapture</li>
               <li>Turn the Other Way</li>
               <li>Darkness Surrounding</li>
               <li>The Art of Subconscious Illusion</li>
               <li>We Come Out at Night</li>
               <li>Lips of Deceit</li>
               <li>Warmness on the Soul</li>
               <li>An Epic of Time Wasted</li>
               <li>Breaking Their Hold</li>
               <li>Forgotten Faces</li>
               <li>Thick and Thin</li>
               <li>Streets</li>
               <li>Shattered by Broken Dreams</li>
             </details>
            <img src="../bilder/Sounding-The-Seventh-Trumpet.jpg" alt="Sounding the Seventh Trumpet Album">
           </div>
         </div>
       </main>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="animation.js"></script>


    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

**Javascript**

    function main() {
      var $body = $("body").hide();
      $("body").fadeIn(1000);
      $('summary').each(function(){
        $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="slide"></div>');
      });
      $('details').attr('open','').find('.slide').css('display','none');
      $('summary').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).siblings('div.slide').slideToggle(function(){
      $(this).parent('details').toggleClass('open');});
      });
      }
    $(document).ready(main);


    function sendToPage(){
      var input = document.getElementById("search").value;
      switch(input){
        case "nightmare":
          location.replace("#Nightmare");
          break;
        case "the stage":
          location.replace("#Hail");
          break;
        case "self":
          location.replace("#Self");
          break;
        case "city":
          location.replace("#City");
          break;
        case "waking":
          location.replace("#Waking");
          break;
        case "sound":
          location.replace("#Sound");
          break;
        default:
          alert("No matching albums, try again!");
          location.replace("file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/projektbrackets/AvengedSevenfold/index.html");
          break;
      }
    }

**CSS**

    * > {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #2c382d;
      font-size: 130%;
    }

    header img {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 30%;
      min-width: 25%;
      border: none;
    }

    input {
      width: 100%;
    }

    nav {
      width: 159px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      min-width: 404px;
      color: white;
    }

    header {
      background-color: #647155;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
    }

    .ram img {
      width: 300px;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
    }

    .wrapper {
      max-width: 100vw;
      min-width: 388px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin-top: 40px;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .ram {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    input {
      width: 155px;
    }

    summary {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 4px;
      border: 1px blue solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 89%;
      }

    li {
      background-color: #212121;
      color: white;
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: center;
      margin-right: 5px;
      font-family: 'Ravi Prakash', cursive;
    }

    header {
      min-width: 420px;
    }

    .hide {
        position: absolute !important;
        top: -9999px !important;
        left: -9999px !important;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
    }

    summary::-webkit-details-marker {
      display: none;
    }
    summary:before {
      content: "►";
    }
    details.open summary:before {
      content: "▼";
    }

    li:nth-child(odd){background-color: crimson;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some plugins like this https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll
or you can use your animate function inside your function.

So your html need to be look like this;

```
<button onclick="sendToPage()">Search</button>
<div style="height:800px; width:800px; background:Red; display:block"></div>
<div id="nightmare" style="height:400px; width:800px; background:black; display:block"></div>
```

and your js is like this;

```
function sendToPage() {
  var searched = $("#search").val().toLowerCase();
  console.log(searched)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + searched).offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

Don't use form action unless you want to make a post or get action. In this case you just want to scroll your page so you don't have to make form actions.

Here the JsBin Example: https://jsbin.com/figatapuqo/edit?html,js,output

PS: You need to make your div's id in lowercase so all your search gonna point right div.

Comment: A great answer man! Any good idea about my second question? :)